# Crystal Report: How to sum a formula for every group

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

everyone. I'm trying to create a SUMMARY based on my created formula on group by CHART_LEVEL1
in image attached;

**Green box code**

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar sumdr;

if sum ({tblgeneralledger.dramount}, {tblgeneralledger.chart_level4_code}) > sum ({tblgeneralledger.cramount}, {tblgeneralledger.chart_level4_code}) then
(
    sumdr := sumdr + sum ({tblgeneralledger.dramount}, {tblgeneralledger.chart_level4_code}) - sum ({tblgeneralledger.cramount}, {tblgeneralledger.chart_level4_code});
    sum ({tblgeneralledger.dramount}, {tblgeneralledger.chart_level4_code}) - sum ({tblgeneralledger.cramount}, {tblgeneralledger.chart_level4_code});
)
else
(
    sumdr := sumdr + 0;
    0;
)
```

**Red box code**

```
Shared StringVar previousGroupName := "";
Shared NumberVar sumdrx;

IF GroupName ({tblGeneralLedger.CHART_lEVEL1_CODE}) <> previousGroupName THEN
(
    previousGroupName := GroupName ({tblGeneralLedger.CHART_lEVEL1_CODE});
        if GroupName ({tblGeneralLedger.CHART_lEVEL1_CODE}) = previousGroupName then
            sumdrx := sumdrx + Sum ({tblGeneralLedger.DRAmount}, {tblGeneralLedger.CHART_lEVEL4_CODE});
sumdrx;
)
```

[Layout of my CR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RkgM.png)

Basically what i'm trying to do is that for every group based on CHART_LEVEL1 will their Summary. In my current code im comparing and current and prev CHART_lEVEL1_CODE if it matches and if do i'll sum it up but the problem is it doesn't work like how i wanted. Looking forward for y'all

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear but I think you are trying to sum something once per group.
The best solution for that use case it to create a Running Total and set the Evaluate option to once per group.

[image]